# Webpack vendor loads chunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a working "Hello, World" Project!

**webpack.config.js:**

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {

    entry: {
        app: "./src/main.js",
        vendor: ["react", "react-dom", "react-router"]
    },

    output: {
        path: __dirname+"/resources",
        publicPath: "/resources/",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({name: "vendor", filename: "vendor.bundle.js"})
    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test : /.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**routes.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './app.jsx';
import Home from './components/home.jsx';

import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory} from 'react-router';


const loadAsync = (promise) => (location, callback) => {
    promise
        .then(module => callback(null, module.default))
        .catch(e => console.warn('Could not load route component', e));
};

export default class Routes extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Router history={hashHistory}>
                <Route path="/" component={App}>
                    <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/hello/:foo" getComponent={loadAsync(System.import('./components/hello.jsx'))} />
                </Route>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

**userbar.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Link} from 'react-router';

export default class Userbar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <Link to="/"><li>Home</li></Link>
                    <Link to="/hello/World"><li>World</li></Link>
                    <Link to="/hello/Universe"><li>Universe</li></Link>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            );
    }
}
```

The hello.jsx returns just a: `Hello, {this.props.params.foo}!`

My only problem is:

The chunks are all properly created by webpack!

But the chunk containing the `hello.jsx (0.bundle.js)` is loaded immediately, not at request!

Network-Inspector(chrome) is telling me that the initiator is "vendor.bundle.js"!

How can I fix that? Loading all chunks on index-load is useless!

**EDIT 1:**

I solved the problem myself!

I implemented the routes.js without the route-tags(now programmatically;[Example](https://github.com/ModusCreateOrg/react-dynamic-route-loading-es6/blob/master/client/pages/routes.js)):

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './app.jsx';
import Home from './components/home.jsx';

import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory} from 'react-router';

function loadRoute(cb) {
  return (module) => cb(null, module.default);
}

const routes = {
    component: App,
    childRoutes: [
        {
            path: "/",
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: "/hello/:foo",
            getComponent(location, cb) {
                System.import('./components/hello.jsx')
                  .then(loadRoute(cb))
                  .catch(errorLoading);
              }
        },
    ]
};

export default () => <Router history={hashHistory} routes={routes} />
```